# Message handler gets overwritten by next message

Tags: java, android, handler

Not new to programming, but fairly new to Java and Android.  App is a Bluetooth SPP receive getting short packets once per second.  Occasionally the Bluetooth gives me a portion of a message and then rapidly after gives me the remainder of the message.  When this happens, my receive thread sends the same type of message to my parser, but with different contents.  However the parser receives the "data" from the second message with the "length" of the first message.

Here's my code and I'm wondering what I should do to differentiate the messages, or if I need to check in my receiver thread as to whether or not the message has been handled and sleep for a few milliseconds and try again.  Opinions?  And sorry, I'm learning by the examples I see, I'm sure there are several ways to do what I'm doing here.

The receiver:

```
protected void receive() {
    byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[128];
    while(inStream != null) {
        try {
            int bytesReceived = inStream.read(recvBuffer);
            System.out.println("BT-In: ");
            String outString = new String(recvBuffer, 0, bytesReceived);
            System.out.println(outString);
            processReceive.obtainMessage(NEW_DEVICE_DATA, bytesReceived, -1, recvBuffer)
                          .sendToTarget();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            WarningBox("Warning", "Receive over Bluetooth did not work, check connection.");      
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

The Handler:

```
Handler processReceive = new Handler() {
@Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
        default:
            break;
        case NEW_DEVICE_DATA:
            byte[] parseInfo = (byte[])msg.obj;
            String outString = new String(parseInfo, 0, msg.arg1);
            System.out.println("Parse-In: ");
            System.out.println(outString);
            //ParseReceivedData(parseInfo);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

For now I'm not parsing the data, but trying to validate that I get everything over the Bluetooth from my remote device and that I'm properly sending that over to the parser which will eventually update my screen fields.

My log might look something like this:

BT-In:
ABCabc

Parse-In:
ABCabc

BT-In:
12

BT-In:
3456789

Parse-In:
34

Parse-In:
3456789

The error there is that I have two Bluetooth receives near each other, say the whole string was "123456789", but I got it in two parts "12" and then "3456789" and I sent those two parts to my parser (main thread), the handler saw two messages, but the first message was accepted properly in size, but improperly in content.

Comment: What kind of device is on the other end? It needs to frame the messages somehow so that you can recognize where one begins and ends (or send message length at the beginning of a message.

Comment: Yes it's framed and I'm seeing the framing, the data I quoted is not actual but simplified to show my problem.  The parser is responsible for dealing with de-framing, my problem is that I'm not seeing the Bluetooth received data verbatim when I send it across to my handler.  If you're thinking that the Bluetooth has performance problems and that I ought to be seeing a once per second 30 character or so message all at once, that's another topic.

Comment: I've used Jerry Li's Bluetooth SPP application and that sees my remote device's data fine.  Also my Bluetooth receiver sees all the data, sometimes an entire packet, and sometimes in two fragments.  The problem is when the Bluetooth receives fragment 1, sends to handler, (handler doesn't yet run), Bluetooth receives fragment 2, sends to handler, handler runs and it has two messages, it sees the length of fragment 1, but sees the data for fragment 2 in the first message and it sees the length for fragment 2 and the data for fragment 2 in the second message.  I misunderstand message handling.